# Передать параметры из контроллера в метод модели

Tags: kohana

Как в kohana передать параметры из контроллера в метод модели?

Comment: @ДМитрий, чем этот вопрос отличается от позавчерашнего [Передача параметра в контроллер Kohana](http://hashcode.ru/questions/322872/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-kohana)?

И всё-таки, что значит передать параметры из контроллера в метод модели? ``$superModel->superMethod($param1, $param2)``?

Comment: там была передача параметра в массив POST из вида, проблема в том, что не могу найти примеры кода под возникающие вопросы, и прежде чем написать сюда, я часок помучался, пытаясь принять параметр в модели и записать его БД

Comment: Там была передача параметра в массив POST из вида, проблема в том, что не могу найти примеры кода под возникающие вопросы, и прежде чем написать сюда, я часок помучался, пытаясь принять параметр в модели и записать его БД.

Вот метод из контроллера  
public function action_expadd()
{  
  $summ = $this->request->post('summ');
  $expadd = new Model_Exp();
  $expadd -> get_expadd($summ);
} 
вот из модели 
public function get_expadd()
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO record VALUES(NULL, $summ)";
  return DB::query(Database::INSERT, $sql)->execute();
}
при выполнении выдает "Undefined variable: summ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот у меня модель `Model_Post`, у неё метод `init()`, контроллер `Controller_Posts` и метод `action_save()`. Я передаю `$title, $text, $author` в метод модели.

```
// model
class Model_Post extends ORM {

    public function init($title, $text, $author)
    {
        // ...
    }

}

// controller
class Controller_Posts extends Controller {

    public function action_save()
    {
        $title = $this->request->post('title');
        $text = $this->request->post('title');
        $author = Auth::instance()->get_user();

        $post = ORM::factory('Post');
        $post->init($title, $text, $author);
        $post->save();
    }

}
```

Оно?

**UPD:**

> вот из модели public function get_expadd()

исправить на

> вот из модели public function get_expadd($summ)

и туда передавать этот самый `$summ`.

Comment: блин...его еще и в модели надо в параметрах указывать, понял, большое спасибо

Comment: Да, надо. Но тут дело не во фреймворке.  
*Я немного напутал с кодом контроллера. Обновил.*

Comment: а чем вас стандартный метод save() в ORM не устроил? И почему в try-catch не оборачиваете конструкцию сохранения?

Comment: @kemerov4anin, чтобы не засорять ответ.  
А что с методом ``save()`` не так?

Comment: можно и выше, но зачем писать свой велосипед, если более корректный велосипед уже написан?

Comment: конкретнее, где велосипед?

Comment: @kemerov4anin, и всё-таки?